# Как реализовать смену модели персонажа в игре на Unity 3d

Tags: unity3d

По задумке, персонаж должен проходить через триггер и менять свою модель на другую, при этом меняя управление. Т.е. если персонаж просто двигался по уровню и преодолевал препятствия, то после триггера он должен сменить свою модель (условно на самолёт), а обычное управление на полёт. Как реализовать это в Unity 3d?

Comment: Finite State Machine, к примеру.

Comment: Поведение как сменный модуль реализует паттерн `Cтратегия`.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker тебе что, человека не жалко? Ну ты садист =D Да и смысла жёсткой регламентации всех переходов одного состояния в другое возможно нет.